# An error was encountered while creating the endpoint in Vertex AI

Tags: endpoint, vertex

I trained a custom model on Vertex AI.Then, I want to deploy the model and get online prediction.But, I failed to create the endpoint.It says:

> "Model server terminated:model server container terminated."

Model server logs show as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhVSD.png)

link：https://cloudlogging.app.goo.gl/VKJphK114GjDsgQS7
It has two extra punctuation marks at the end of location.

Everytime I create a new endpoint, it shows up like this.
How can I avoid this?